# Jersey: HTTP Status 500.The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request error

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a UserResource (root) class looks like this:

```
@Path("users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResource {

    //....

    // Subresource
    @Path("/{userId}/adverts")
    public AdvertResource getAdvertResource() {
       return new AdvertResource();
    }
}
```

AdvertResource class is a subresource and handles request from: `http://localhost:8080/appName/api/users/1/adverts` and looks like this:

```
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AdvertResource {

    //...

    @GET
    public List<Advert> getAll(@PathParam("userId") int userId) {
        return this.advertFacade.findAllByUserId(userId);
    }
}
```

`getAll` method gets all items from database. In debug mode I can see userId is correct and `advertFacade` returns a correct list of adverts. But I receive "`HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request`" in web browser. No exception output in serverlog!

When I change the method to something like this:

```
@GET
public String getAll(@PathParam("userId") int userId) {
    return "User ID is: " + userId;
}
```

It is working fine and I get output  `User ID is: 99` for http://localhost:8080/appName/api/users/99/adverts

I created project from archetype: `jersey-quickstart-ejb` `org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes` and I use Glassfish 4.1. My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>appName</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>appName</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>appName</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>   -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
            <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Debug [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33379590/2587435). I'm sure you will get a stacktrace telling you what's wrong. My guess is you're getting an NPE on `abstractFacade`, since you said it works without it.

Comment: @peeskillet thank you for you comment but `abstractFacade` working just fine. I get list of adverts from database. I will try debug as you suggested anyway.